# Google Script number format in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm currently generating a google document with Google Script.

I have an issue with number formats. I have a table with currency values, so I tried to format the text like this ( like how I'd do it normally ):

```
var number = 12345;
var currencyString = number.toLocaleString(); // This 'works' but outputs : 12345
var euroCurrencyString = number.toLocaleString("nl-NL", { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }); // This throws exception
```

But it throws this exception: 
TypeError: InternalError: Illegal radix 0.

Is there any other way to format a number to a currency string? ( eq; € 12.345,00 )

EDIT: toLocaleString() actually works, I just mistyped it

Comment: Remove the "s" in `toLocalseString`.

Comment: derp, I edited my question :) toLocaleString() seems to work, but does not output it in a way I want it to. When I supply parameters to it, it fails.

Comment: `.toLocaleString()` (without arguments) doesn't even seem to work. I can't get it to display anything other than `[object String]`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did anyone solve it?